# python how to change code to recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

This is the python code that prints files in a sub-directory.(not current directory)
I want to change this code to recursive function (using a recursive call) how can I change it?

```py
def search_file(dirpath):
    filenames = os.listdir(dirpath)
    for filename in filenames:
        fullname = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        if os.path.isdir(fullname):
            os.chdir(fullname)
            sub_filenames = os.listdir(fullname)
            for sub_filename in sub_filenames:
                print(sub_filename)
```

Comment: When you encounter a directory, just call `search_file` to handle it.  That's a recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

As Tom said, you just need to call the function again when you encounter a directory. If it is not a directory, you just print the name out.

```
def search_file(dirpath):
   filenames = os.listdir(dirpath)

   for filename in filenames:
        fullname = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        if os.path.isdir(fullname):
            search_file(fullname)
        else:
            print(fullname)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But this code prints the contents of the current directory too. Can't  I changes so that only the contents of the subdirectory are showed?

Comment: @mia There are a few options for fixing that. You could filter out the folders you want from the target directory then call `search_file` on each of those. Another option would be to added another parameter to the `search_file` function so you have `search_file(dirpath, topmost)`. `topmost` is boolean and you can check that value before doing your `print`.